# How to input time to a neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am working with a time-series, and believe that time in seconds since start is a useful feature. I am however not sure how to best input this to my recurrent neural network.
I don't think the naive approach of just entering the naive value is the best way, and I also don't think that letting the RNN keep track of it on its own is good either.

What has been done before, and what considerations should I keep in mind if I want to use time as an input variable?

---

**Clarification**

Let's say that at each time step, `t` (seconds as integers, ~0-1800), I have a feature vector `x`.
I believe knowing the value of `t` is useful i.e. how much time has elapsed since the start of a process. How do I best input `t` to the network? I.e. is there something better than `concat(x, t)`?

Comment: Which are your reasons to think that just entering the value is not the best way?

Comment: The range of values is quite large, roughly $\in [0, 1800]$, and from my experience that is not very nice for a neural network. This is somewhat alleviated by batch normalization, I was just wondering if there were some best practices.

Comment: Would scaling solve the range problem?

Comment: Scaling how? Just $t'=t/1800$? or do you mean log scaling? Linear scaling is redundant because of batch norm. I don't know if log scaling is smart

Comment: Doesn't the fact that linear scaling is redundant imply that the large range of values wouldn't be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially applying a recurrent neural network to solve a Markov problem. The neural network can be trained to learn a so-called hidden Markov model, in your time data. You try to predict the probabilities of the possible next states at time $t$, given the current state $t-1$, the previous states (represented by feature variables), and state information: $t-2$, $t-3$, $\ldots$.

One first question you need to address, is whether the state at $t-2$ has any extra predictive power as to which next state is being reached. As the underlying mechanism is assumed to be unknown, you ought to experiment with this - adding or retracting historic, previous state information from your recurrent neural network.

There are basically two alternative strategies to follow: They both involve training the RNN to *convolve* along the time/state axis. According to one strategy, you ridirect the output vector of the RNN to special input units, which exist alongside the regular feature-input nodes. According to the other strategy, you provide the vector of hidden-node values to the special input units. The implicit assumption of both these approaches is that you are dealing with a first-order Markov chain. State-information *before* $t-1$ is completely incorporated into the current state.

Keep a subset of your data as a separate test set.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I meant. I have added a clarification